# MySql Stored Procedure how to approach?

Tags: mysql, triggers, procedure

Trying to get a trigger to work that refuses to I think it has to be setup as a procedure for it to work which I've never worked with before could anyone tell me how I would go about this? The trigger doesn't show errors when adding but just doesn't do anything

** It now does work apart from changing processed to 0)

```
UPDATE product
INNER JOIN ebaylinked ON ebaylinked.ebay_ID = product.eBay_ID
SET product.product_stock = product.product_stock - NEW.QuantitySold,NEW.Processed=0
WHERE product.eBay_ID = NEW.ebay_ID and NEW.Processed = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, find a more descriptive name for your trigger ;).

Now for the actual problem, your references to the columns in `ebaylinked` in your trigger code are pretty much mostly wrong. To use the values in the record you just updated, you need to use the pseudorecord `NEW`, which is a single record containing the current row of the table ***as it will be after the update completes.*** References like `ebaylinked.QuantitySold` are ambiguous, as they do not specify *which row of data* is the correct one.

Also, you ***cannot*** refer to other rows in the triggering table. Your clauses `SET ... ebaylinked.Processed=0 ... WHERE ... ebaylinked.Processed = 1` are thus both redundant and wrong, since the only row of `ebaylinked` your row trigger can see is the current one.

Your trigger code should thus be something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER `ebaylinked_update_product`
  AFTER UPDATE ON `ebaylinked`
  FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE product
      SET product.product_stock = product.product_stock - NEW.QuantitySold
      WHERE product.eBay_ID = NEW.ebay_ID;
```

Note I'm ignoring the `processed` column since it does nothing useful (provided the triggering **insert** is wrapped in a transaction), but if you *absolutely must* use it, you would change your trigger to **before row** as follows:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `ebaylinked_update_product`
  BEFORE UPDATE ON `ebaylinked`
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF NEW.processed = 1 THEN
      UPDATE product
        SET product.product_stock = product.product_stock - NEW.QuantitySold
        WHERE product.eBay_ID = NEW.ebay_ID;
      SET NEW.processed = 0;
    END IF;
  END;
  //

  DELIMITER ;
```

Note the space between `DELIMITER` and whatever follows it. This directive is necessary in some clients when the trigger body contains multiple statements terminated by semicolons.

Hope that helps.

PS: You *could* do this with the trigger calling a stored procedure, but for something this simple I think it would add more complexity than it would be worth.

Comment: this does the same adds but doesnt update anything,I've checked all the fields are right and they are so very confused with whats going on with it

Comment: Just so we're both on the same page, describe for me in your own words what you want this trigger to do.

Comment: I messed up and had update on instead of on insert everything works with the new one I have apart from changing processed field to 0 which seems to be ignored? Ill change top question to code I have now

Comment: You can't modify `NEW` in an **after row** trigger. (Well, you can, but it doesn't do anything useful.) The column `processed` also does nothing useful, since presumably you're inserting the value `1` and then the trigger is changing it to `0` *as part of the same insert operation.*

Comment: a php script inserts the value 1 in when pulled from ebay API the 1 is there as a check to ensure it hasn't already been used to update stock before changing values in product table

Comment: That's rather a fragile way of doing it. You're relying on the success of an update to indicate whether an update has succeeded; if the second update fails you end up running the first update twice anyway. You'd do better to wrap the **INSERT** in a transaction (which requires the table be InnoDB) so that ***EITHER*** *both* the insert into `ebaylinked` *and* the update of `product` *succeed* ***OR*** *both* operations *fail*.

Comment: If you insist on using the `processed` column, then you need to use a **before row** trigger; I'll add the code to my answer above.

Comment: It's not anything that will ever be used properly its for a demo so it was more just getting it to look like there is a basic attempt to stop it from being entered twice, im assuming its not possible anyway ? if so I'll get the processed field removed, thanks for your help btw

Comment: Just tried that other one and it says '#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8 ' is that something to do with the MYSql being the wrong type or something wrong in the code? I can't see anything clear from looking at it

Comment: Using a transaction will prevent double-processing under any normal and most abnormal circumstances. To show that you've accounted for the unavoidable edge cases, you could periodically (eg. once daily) run a maintenance query that checks that the current value of `product_stock` is what it should be.

Comment: Right. The line `NEW.processed = 0;` should have been `SET NEW.processed = 0;`

Comment: Still getting, #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8 =S

Comment: Okay. You need to wrap it in `DELIMITER` directives. I'll add them to my answer.

Comment: Came up with an error and then still went in and works now so thanks alot really helped!

Answer (score 0):

What is `ebaylinked`?  You should be getting an error when you define the trigger.

If you want to update the table defined by the trigger, then you should use a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger.  So, I think you intend:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `Update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `ebaylinked`
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE product p
        SET p.product_stock = p.product_stock - new.QuantitySold
        WHERE p.eBay_ID = new.ebay_ID AND new.Processed = 1;

    SET new.Processed = 0;
END; $$

DELIMTER ;
```

Comment: I get this when trying to use that code, #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.Processed = 0;
END' at line 8

Comment: @jamescox . . . Oops, missing the `set`.